# Calculation should wait for Dispatcher

Tags: wpf, timer, wait, dispatcher

I have an algorithmic calculation using depth-first search (sudoku solver) and I want to have a way to control the update rate of the ui to display all/most of the numbers that are calced during the calculation.

I know this slows down the calc time, but the visual feedback is more important to me.

Currently the ui elements, each representing a field in a sudoku game, are bound via binding to the data sources with binding mode "oneway".

I came across `Dispatcher.Invoke` and called that method with a low priority after a datasource send the value changed event, and now one can see how a part of the calculation progress is displayed at least, but it s still way too fast.
So my question is, how do I manage it, that my calculation waits for the Dispatcher thread to display a changed value before calculating the next (changed) value?

Comment: Your view model should update its properties (binding sources) slow enough. You could use a timer there, e.g. a DispatcherTimer.

Comment: Can also use a BackgroundWorker with ReportsProgress

Comment: _"waits for the Dispatcher thread to display a changed value"_ does not seem a meaningful measure of time and anyway it will be quite short.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to use either a storyboard animation or a timer.

Have a look at **[DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx)** it sounds like what you **really are after**. Use a queue/list and then gradually add solved items at your desired rate to your presentation in the view. In the example below I assume you have a clas called `SudokuItem`. The `timer_Tick` method will be invoke every seccond, which is controlled by the `Interval` property. I just grab and remove the first item in the `queue`. You may set the `Dispatcher` property on the `DispatcherTimer`. There is a fictional `SudokuService` there, which simulates generation of items.

#### Simple Example - Can bee refactored. No async-await here etc.

```
protected ISudokuService SudokuService; // Fictional TDD Service for handling generation of Sudoku boards
private List<SudokuItem> queue = new List<SudokuItem>(); 
private DispatcherTimer timer;
private ObservableCollection<SudokuItem> sudokuItems = new ObservableCollection<SudokuItem>();

public ObservableCollection<SudokuItem> SudokuItems
{
    get { return sudokuItems; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, sudokuItems)) return;
        sudokuItems = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public void StartGeneration()
{
    new Thread(DoYourSudokuMagic).Start(); // Start heavy lifting in a separate thread
    timer = new DispatcherTimer {Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1), IsEnabled = true};
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

private void DoYourSudokuMagic()
{
    // fetch/generate new SudokuItems somehow... replace this with your code
    SudokoService.StartGeneratingBoard();
    while( SudokuService.HasMoreItems ){
        var items = SudokoService.GetNextItems();
        if (items != null && items.Any())
        {
            lock (queue)
            {
                queue.AddRange(items);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Always invoked on the Dispatcher thread
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // note that you must call timer.Stop(); when you are done
    lock (queue)
    {
        if (queue.Any())
        {
            SudokuItems.Add(queue.FirstOrDefault());
            queue.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Another timer you can use, which really is for forms, is the **[BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)** class, it could be practical in your case.

**[Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx)** blocks until it gets access. **[Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx)** continues your code, and let you update your Properties or DependencyProperties when it gets access. You  should also check for access first, I typically put this in a baseclass.

```
// Note that Dispatcher is an interface in this baseclass for TDD, you have to set it or replace it with your dispatcher.
protected void BeginInvoke(Action action, DispatcherPriority priority)
{
    if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, priority); // doesn't block
    else
        action(); // hey we are on the gui thread already :)
}

protected void Invoke(Action action, DispatcherPriority priority)
{
    if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        Dispatcher.Invoke(action, priority); // blocks
    else
        action(); // hey we are on the gui thread already :)
}
```

I hope this is of some help, and that I haven't missunderstood your question.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is, how do I manage it, that my calculation waits for the Dispatcher thread to display a changed value before calculating the next (changed) value?

That's not really what you want to do. You really just want to throttle the updates.

The standard modern way of doing CPU-bound operations with UI updates is to use `Task.Run` and `IProgress<T>`. So, I'll assume that your CPU-bound code looks something like this:

```
struct SolveProgress { ... }
void Solve(IProgress<SolveProgress> progress)
{
  while (...)
  {
    ...
    if (progress != null)
      progress.Report(new SolveProgress(...));
  }
}
async void Button_Click()
{
  var progress = new Progress<SolveProgress>(value =>
  {
    // Update UI
  });
  await Task.Run(() => Solve(progress));
}
```

The problem is that the background work is issuing lots of updates. What you want is a consistent UI experience across various computer capabilities, no more than a few times per second. Personally, I really like 100ms updates - it's just enough to convey the feeling "this software is working really hard" while still being "seeable". If you want it more readable, 250ms may be better.

Throttling is a time-based operation, and I like to use Rx for anything time-based. First, replace the `Progress<T>` implementation (which just executes the delegate for *every* progress) with an [`ObserverProgress<T>` that converts progress updates into an observable stream](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/4248e50b4cb52b933c0d). This type is very simple:

```
public sealed class ObservableProgress<T> : IObservable<T>, IProgress<T>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly Subject<T> _subject = new Subject<T>();

    void IProgress<T>.Report(T value)
    {
        _subject.OnNext(value);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _subject.Dispose();
    }

    IDisposable IObservable<T>.Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        return _subject.Subscribe(observer);
    }
}
```

Then the consuming code looks like this (after installing the NuGet packages Rx and Rx-WPF):

```
using (var progress = new ObservableProgress<SolveProgress>())
using (progress.ObserveOn(this)
    .Subscribe(value =>
    {
        // Update UI
    }))
{
    await Task.Run(() => Solve(progress));
}
```

`ObservableProgress<T>` by default will *not* synchronize to the UI thread like `Progress<T>` will, so that's why the `ObserveOn` is necessary. With this in place, it's easy to throttle the progress updates:

```
using (var progress = new ObservableProgress<SolveProgress>())
using (progress.Sample(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
    .ObserveOn(this)
    .Subscribe(value =>
    {
        // Update UI
    }))
{
    await Task.Run(() => Solve(progress));
}
```

A nice benefit of the Rx approach is that the throttling logic is done on the background thread; it only switches to the UI thread when it has some UI work to do. This means that the time-based throttling is actually done at the source, saving CPU cycles. Since it's time-based (and not, e.g., using a counter), you get a reliable, smooth user experience, whether running on an older machine or a newer one.